# Magento Web Services Guide to check

Tags: magento-1.6, web-services

I am new to magento web services, but i want to create create or use web services.
So any one help to guide where to start and how to check,

As i have created user for web services and i don't know how to check the magento web services.

I have searched lot i am getting the codes but i don't know where to place these codes and how to check.

This may be silly question,
I need help on this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test the examples provided [in here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/146) you can simply create a php (call it `api_test.php`) file with the contents from one of the examples and just call it in the browser. `http://somedomain.com/api_test.php`. It does not have to be on the same domain as your magento instance.

For a nicer UI I recommend using [soapUi](http://www.soapui.org/). It is a java tool that let's you test your SOAP (seams it supports REST also).
Just create a new SOAP project, fill in the url of your wsdl and enjoy.

For API v1 the wsdl url is `http://your_magento_root/api/soap/?wsdl=1`
For API v2 the wsdl url is `http://your_magento_root/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1`

Answer (score 1):

The following links will guide you to create web services in Magento. Before you start creating a new web service, try to get a better understanding of the theory behind the magento web services. (First two articles will guide you for this)

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/setting-web-services

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-api-v2/

http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-programming/629-connecting-to-magento-with-soap-part-1

http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/extending-magento-web-services-api

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/custom-api

http://greladesign.com/blog/2010/09/13/how-to-create-magentos-custom-api/

http://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magebridge/basics/596-step-by-step-create-a-magento-api-user

Comment: thanks for help, but i need to know how to check